# How to use map-function in SPARK with Java with another class method

Tags: java, dictionary, apache-spark

```
    public class RDDExample {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        final JavaSparkContext sc = SparkSingleton.getContext();
        Lemmatizer lemmatizer = new Lemmatizer();
        List<String> dirtyTwits = Arrays.asList(
                "Shipment of gold arrived in a truck",
                "Delivery of silver arrived in a silver truck",
                "Shipment of gold damaged in a fire"
                //итд, дофантазируйте дальше сами :)
        );
        JavaRDD<String> twitsRDD = sc.parallelize(dirtyTwits);

        JavaRDD<List<String>> lemmatizedTwits = twitsRDD.map(new Function<String, List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
                return lemmatizer.Execute(s);//return List<String>
            }
        });
        System.out.println(lemmatizedTwits.collect());
    }
}
```

I write it code, but in runtime I have exception **Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable**.
I am search it in google, but need for me solution for Java not found.
Everywhere code for Scala or easy operations "return s+"qwer"".
Where I might read how use methods from another classes in .map? Or may be who say me how it work? Sorry for my english.
**Full traceback**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.map(JavaRDD.scala:32)
    at RDDExample.main(RDDExample.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: preprocessor.coreNlp.Lemmatizer
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 11 more
```

**Full log**

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/01/15 00:45:49 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ntsfk
17/01/15 00:45:49 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ntsfk
17/01/15 00:45:49 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(ntsfk); users with modify permissions: Set(ntsfk)
17/01/15 00:45:50 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
17/01/15 00:45:50 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
17/01/15 00:45:51 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@localhost:64122]
17/01/15 00:45:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 64122.
17/01/15 00:45:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/01/15 00:45:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/01/15 00:45:51 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at F:\Local\Temp\spark-local-20170115004551-eaac
17/01/15 00:45:51 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 491.7 MB
17/01/15 00:45:52 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/01/15 00:45:53 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is F:\Local\Temp\spark-e041cd0f-83b9-46fa-b5d0-4fce800a2778
17/01/15 00:45:53 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
17/01/15 00:45:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 64123.
17/01/15 00:45:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/01/15 00:45:53 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://DESKTOP-B29B6NA:4040
17/01/15 00:45:54 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@localhost:64122/user/HeartbeatReceiver
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 64134
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:64134 with 491.7 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 64134)
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO StanfordCoreNLP: Adding annotator tokenize
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO TokenizerAnnotator: TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO StanfordCoreNLP: Adding annotator ssplit
17/01/15 00:45:55 INFO StanfordCoreNLP: Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [3,5 sec].
17/01/15 00:45:59 INFO StanfordCoreNLP: Adding annotator lemma
```

After I have exception.

Enviroment Java 1.8, Spark 2.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the first method of choice would be to make `Lemmatizer` `Serializable` but you have to remember that serialization is not the only possible problem here. Spark executors depend heavily on multi-threading and any objects in closures should be thread safe.

If satisfying both conditions (serializability and thread-safety) an alternative solution is to create separate instances for each executor thread, for example with `mapPartitions`. A naive solution (in general it is better to avoid collecting a whole partition) can be sketched as follows:

```
twitsRDD.mapPartitions(iter -> {
    Lemmatizer lemmatizer = new Lemmatizer();
    List<List<String>> lemmas = new LinkedList<>();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        lemmas.add(lemmatizer.Execute(iter.next()));
    }

    return lemmas.iterator();
});
```

This should resolve serialization issues and address some, but not all, of the thread safety concerns. Since recent versions of the CoreNLP claim to be thread-safe it should good enough in your case.